# Trying to get the user to input numbers and when the user hits end the program will stop in a while loop and give the sum of numbers

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get a while loop in my C# program to get the user to enter a number. When their finish they'll input end and the while loop will stop and add up all the numbers the user has entered. I don't know where to store the text End in my while loop

```
List <int> nums = new List <int>();
int sum = nums.Sum();
string enteredText = "";

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number or the word End to finish : ");
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    // nums.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

    if (enteredText.Equals("End"))
    {
        break;
    }
}
// Console.WriteLine("The sum is: " + sum);
// Console.WriteLine($"Sum = {nums.Sum()}");
```

Comment: You're converting the input to an `int` on the same line you're reading it. Split it so you can reference your input later.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to programming. Can you give me some guidance on how to write it ?

Comment: Or can you provide a resource that can give me an example ?

Answer (score 1):

First thing if the entred string contains characters `Convert.ToInt32 Method` gives error because this string cannot be converted to integer.

but you can using the `int.TryParse Method` to convert a string representation of number to an integer, if the string cannot be converted, then the `int.TryParse Method` returns false ,and if conversion succeeded, the method will return true.

*The solution:*

```
List <int> nums = new List <int>();
int number = 0;
string enteredText = string.Empty;

while (true) {
  Console.Write("Enter a number or the word End to finish : ");
  enteredText = Console.ReadLine();
  //check if enteredText is int type 
  if (int.TryParse(enteredText, out number)) {
    nums.Add(number);
  }
  else if (enteredText.Equals("End")) {
    break;
  }
}
Console.WriteLine($"Sum = {nums.Sum()}");
Console.ReadKey();
```